# remove part of matcher after the match in regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need to help in writing regex pattern to remove only part of the matcher from original string.

**Original String:** `2017-02-15T12:00:00.268+00:00`

**Expected String:** `2017-02-15T12:00:00+00:00`

Expected String removes everything in milliseconds.

**My regex pattern** looks like this:     `(:[0-5][0-9])\.[0-9]{1,3}`

i need this regex to make sure i am removing only the milliseconds from some time field, not everything that comes after dot. But using above regex, I am also removing the minute part. Please suggest and help.

Comment: Replace with `$1`.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate more?

Comment: Yes, [see here](http://ideone.com/oVX1mr) ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hzt059/1)).

Comment: Looks promosing, but how can i handle this as part of java code, what is this $ all about?

Comment: What part of Java code? Post yours (edit the question).

Comment: Can you please clarify your requirement? Do you want to remove the milliseconds part alone? If so, you don't need a regex matching the seconds part (since the milliseconds can be uniquely identified from the preceding dot).

Comment: If you need a full answer with explanation please add your relevant code to the question.

Comment: I think, i got it worked with $1 replacement, All I need to understand how does it work?

Comment: OK, then I will post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a [*capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with `(...)` in your pattern, and you want to have that part of string to be present after the replacement is performed. All you need is to use a [*backreference*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to the value stored in this capture. It can be done with `$1`:

```
String s = "2017-02-15T12:00:00.268+00:00";
String res = s.replaceFirst("(:[0-5][0-9])\\.[0-9]{1,3}", "$1");
System.out.println(res); // => 2017-02-15T12:00:00+00:00
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/oVX1mr) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hzt059/1).

The `$1` in the replacement pattern tells the regex engine it should look up the captured group with ID 1 in the match object data. Since you only have one pair of unescaped parentheses (1 capturing group) the ID of the group is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Change your pattern to `(?::[0-5][0-9])(\.[0-9]{1,3})`, run the `find` in the matcher and remove all it finds in the `group(1)`.

The backslash will force the match with the '.' char, instead of any char, which is what the dot represents in a regex.

The `(?:` defines a non-capturing group, so it will not be considered in the `group(...)` on the matcher.

And adding a parenthesis around what you want will make it show up as group in the matcher, and in this case, the first group.

A good reference is the Pattern javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: No, I need to make sure that i want to delete anything which is time that i confirm via ":" tag

Answer (score 1):

Use $1 and $2 variable for replace

```
string.replaceAll("(.*)\\.\\d{1,3}(.*)","$1$2");
```